# Type Mismatch error second time through

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the code below to find text in a worksheet then loop through and find the next occurrence until it can't find any new occurrences. But I get a Runtime Error 13; Type Mismatch error when a I run it a second time. It works the first time but generates the error on the second run through the code.

The type mismatch error occurs at the  Set currentFind... line

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSh As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rcell As Range
Dim int_row As Integer
Dim str_platelet_count_address As String
Dim int_firstFind_count As Integer


Dim currentFind As Excel.Range
Dim d As Excel.Range
Dim str_firstFind_address As String
Dim bln_found As Boolean
Dim str_din As String
Dim int_platelet_count As Integer



Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 xlApp.Visible = True
 xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False  ' ensures Excel default which is to overwrite files


Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Me.txt_workday_file, True, False)
Set xlSh = xlWB.ActiveSheet
xlSh.Range("A1").Select




Set currentFind = xlSh.Cells.Find(What:="W2017", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False)



If currentFind Is Nothing Then

    MsgBox "Can't find"
    GoTo Close_workbook
Else

    str_firstFind_address = currentFind.Address
    currentFind.Select

End If


Do Until currentFind Is Nothing


        int_row = ActiveCell.Row
        str_din = ActiveCell.Value
        str_platelet_count_address = "J" & int_row - 1
        int_platelet_count = Range(str_platelet_count_address).Value

    msgbox "Found"

 Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate


 If str_firstFind_address = ActiveCell.Address Then
    int_firstFind_count = int_firstFind_count + 1
 End If

 If int_firstFind_count >= 1 Then GoTo Close_workbook


Loop

Close_workbook:
    xlWB.Close
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set currentFind = Nothing
    Set xlWB = Nothing

    Set xlSh = Nothing

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveCell` and `xlSh.Cells` are almost certainly in different instances of Excel on the second time through.  Try using `xlApp.ActiveCell`.  (And also change all your other `ActiveCell` references - without qualification they are forcing your first instance of Excel to be kept in memory until you exit whatever application you are in.)  And you also have an unqualified `Cells` in `Cells.FindNext`.

Comment: That worked.  Thanks